# Flutter Retrofit upload file

Tags: flutter, dart, retrofit

I'm working with the flutter Retrofit package, am trying to upload data to the server (Laravel). basically, the file should be sent as MultiPart part annotation. in addition, I should send with the file (in my case a picture) different values, so I used @Part() map<String, dynamic>.

this is my code

```
@POST('register')
  Future<RegisterResponse> register(@Body() Map<String, dynamic> body, @Part() File pic);
```

and this is my request

```
Map<String, dynamic> body = {
                            "name":" widget.fullName",
                            "username": "widget.userName",
                            "phone": "698281556",
                            "country_code": "+213",
                            "email": "widget.email@gmail.com",
                            "birth_date": "18-09-2021",
                            "pic": imageFile,
                            "lat": 36.347285,
                            "lon": 6.603381,
                            "address": "widget.userName",
                            "city": "widget.userName",
                            "residential": "widget.userName",
                            "device_token": "widget.userName",
                            "code": "123456",
                            "tags": [1,2]
                          };

                          final logger = Logger();
                          final dio = Dio(); // Provide a dio instance
                          dio.options.headers["Content-Type"] =
                          "multipart/form-data";
                          dio.options.headers["X-Requested-With"] =
                          "XMLHttpRequest";
                          final client = RestClient(dio);

                          client.register(body,imageFile!).then((it) async {

                            print(it.access_token);

                          }).catchError((Object obj) {

                            // non-200 error goes here.
                            switch (obj.runtimeType) {
                              case DioError:
                              // Here's the sample to get the failed response error code and message
                                final res = (obj as DioError).response;
                                logger.e(
                                    "Got error : ${res!.statusCode} -> ${res.data}");
                                break;
                              default:
                            }
                          });
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. there is not enough documentation for that. thank you for help

Answer (score 17):

Unfortunately the documentation doesn't mention that.
You have to annotate your request using `@Multipart` in order to be able to upload files.

Another case you must pay attention is that when you annotate your request using `@Multipart` , you must annotate all of the fields using `@Part`. even those which are not files.

An example:

```
  @POST('/store')
  @MultiPart()
  Future<dynamic> store({
    @Part() required String title,
    @Part() required int part,
    @Part() File? attach,
  });
```

Comment: its better to set content type for files that set in @Part, => @Part( name: 'file', contentType: 'image/png')File? file,

Comment: this won't work if you are posing an list of objects alongside request multipart file

Comment: @AbdulmalekDery You're right, though this issue is supposed to be solved as [here](https://github.com/trevorwang/retrofit.dart/pull/158) but I think using `MultipartFile` as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74774017/11799781) is better to avoid this.

Answer (score 3):

Great answer from Xoltawn. Keep in mind that the file from 'dart:io' and not 'dart:html' must be used!