# POST list of files using Retrofit

Tags: flutter, retrofit

I'm using the [retrofit](https://pub.dev/packages/retrofit) package in order to generate HTTP requests within my app. I want to upload multiple files to our servers. The number of files **is unknown** (the list is dynamic).

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69734592/12695188) that describes how to upload one
file using retrofit:

```
@POST('/store')
  @MultiPart()
  Future<dynamic> store({
    @Part() required String title,
    @Part() File? attach,
  });
```

I'm looking to upload a **list** of files `List<File>`.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Problem Solved.

I was able to send multiple files by adding the `@MultiPart()` annotation and sending the files as a `List<MultipartFile>`:

```
@POST('/your/api/url')
@MultiPart()
Future<List<S3FilesResponse>> uploadFilesToS3({
  @Part() required String folderName,
  @Part() required List<MultipartFile> files,
});
```

In order to convert `List<File>` to `List<MultipartFile>` I had to do the following:

```
final multipartFiles = <MultipartFile>[];

for (final file in files) {
  final fileBytes = await file.readAsBytes();
  final multipartFile = MultipartFile.fromBytes(
    fileBytes,
    filename: file.path.split('/').last,
    contentType: MediaType('application', 'octet-stream'),
  );
  multipartFiles.add(multipartFile);
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. If anyone can't find MediaType, use import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';

And if you are trying to upload an image, make sure to set it to MediaType('image', 'jpeg') or whichever format you detect.