# Flutter Dio: Image or File Upload Using Retrofit

Tags: flutter, retrofit, multipart, form-data, dio

i am new to the flutter and i am trying to upload single or multiple images from my Flutter Application using Retrofit via @MultiPart() . I have to upload it using **form-data** Content-Type, but i am unable to find any good reference for it, can anyone please help me. i am sharing the way i am currently implementing it but i didn't got any success till now

i have tried this
In my @RestApi file i have created a function like below

```
@POST('$ENDPOINTS')
@MultiPart()
Future<dynamic> uploadImage(
    @Header("Authorization") authorization,
    @Part(name: 'file') File image,
    @Part(name: 'filetype') String fileType
    );
```

and called this function like

```
File file = File(imagePath);


response = await apiClient
    .someClass()
    .uploadImage("myToken", file, "imageType");
```

Can anyone please help

Comment: checkout this, it may answer your qeustion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69507817/flutter-retrofit-upload-file